# smooth scrolling complete website with custom designed scrollbar

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, smooth-scrolling, custom-scrolling

I am working on a website client requirements for website custom design scrollbar with smoothing like give URL. 
http://www.sezane.com/denim/

I tried nice scroll and simplr.smoothscroll but it didn't work for me.Help is really apriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found smooth scrollbar plugin for my project.

http://idiotwu.github.io/smooth-scrollbar/

It's work perfectly.